# ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper excerpt helper is not fully functional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using module `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` to generate an excerpt from a text. If a word exists more than once, it will just excerpt the first occurrence.

> <%= excerpt('Hello, i am a Ruby lover, a Rails lover and would never come back to PHP', 'lover', :radius => 5) %>
>   `"...lover,..."`

I was expecting the return string to be something like, becauee there two occurrences of the word 'lover':

> "...lover,...lover ..."

How can i get it to work to display multiple occurrences of a keyword?

I am using rails 3.2.11.

Comment: Your intention under the expected output is not clear. You need to explain it.

Comment: i am just expecting a larger result if i have multiple occurrences of the phrase i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excerpt(text, phrase, options = {}) Link:

Extracts an excerpt from text that matches the first instance of phrase. The :radius option expands the excerpt on each side of the first occurrence of phrase

as the documantation states, is only the first instance of the phrase you search, not every instance of it

Comment: is there something that will find all the instances or do i have to code it?

Comment: im guessing you have to code it, never crossed across of something like that

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a multi_excerpt() method defined in my application_helper.rb

```
# Returns a summary of +text+ in the form of +phrase+ excerpts
#
#   multi_excerpt('This string is is a very long long long string ', 'string', radius: 5)
#   # => ...This string is i...long string ...
def multi_excerpt(text, phrase, options = {})
  return unless text && phrase

  radius   = options.fetch(:radius, 10)
  omission = options.fetch(:omission, "...")

  raise if phrase.is_a? Regexp
  regex = /.{,#{radius}}#{Regexp.escape(phrase)}.{,#{radius}}/i
  parts = text.scan(regex)
  "#{omission}#{parts.join(omission)}#{omission}"
end
```

Linking here my related [post](https://www2.sam-we.com/bf573c716116ed5b9d0c445be65be9a6) and [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35939).